# Disable raid member check upon mount to mount damaged nvidia raid1 member

Tags: raid, mount, graphics-processing-unit

A friend of mine destroyed his Nvidia RAID1 array somehow and in trying to fix it, he ended up with a non-working array. Because of the RAID metadata, the actual disk data was stored at an offset from the beginning. I was able to identify this offset with dd and a hexeditor and then I used losetup to create a loop device with the proper offset, so that I could mount the partition.

It was then that I ran into problems, namely that mount says: "mount: unknown filesystem type 'nvidia_raid_member'". I also had this when trying to mount a Linux MD component the other day, and because I can remember that doing that in the past worked, I surmised that it may be some kind of protection. I therefore booted an old Sysrescue CD and tried it there, which worked (because of the older version of mount/libc/kernel/whatever).

I still need to try to get more data, and because I don't want to keep using that SysrecueCD, I'd like to be able to mount the disk on my normal system.

So, my question is: can the check for a disk being a raid member be disabled?

I guess I could also zero out blocks that look like the raid block, but I'd rather not... I made an image of the disk with par2 data, so it's revertable, but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a late answer, but I worked around this with the Linux fakeraid tools. I don't remember how (too long ago), but I managed to use device mapper to assemble the array in degraded mode with one disk and access the new virtual device.